# Как написать сайт на Python без использования фреймворков?

Tags: python, веб-программирование

Возник вопрос: как пишутся сайты на Питоне? Прочитал почти половину учебника, использую встроенный интерпретатор на линуксе, но все равно не могу понять, как использовать Питон для создания сайта.

Забыл написать, что хотелось бы обойтись без фреймворков (т.е. написать свой). Никакой информации в инете я не нашел.

Comment: Вообще, по-хорошему, это вопрос не для этого сайта. Вопрос крайне расплывчатый. В чем конкретно вы видите проблему?

Comment: А какие принципиально новые возможности дает написание сайта на питоне? Хочу изучить, но не знаю принесет ли это какую-то пользу

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Обычно используют какой-нибудь web-фреймворк http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Рекомендую начать с [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/)

```
from wsgiref import simple_server

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-type', 'text/plain')])
    return ['Hello world!']

server = simple_server.WSGIServer(('', 8000), simple_server.WSGIRequestHandler)
server.set_app(app)
server.serve_forever()
```

Вот простейший код, отдающий HTML страницу по http://127.0.0.1:8000
Но не стоит городить велосипед. Есть огромное количество легких фреймворков, от которых можно использовать только нужные компоненты - роутинг, шаблонизатор итд.

Comment: И как воспользоваться этим кодом? Тоесть меня интересует, как именно осуществляется взаимодействие со скриптом (при создании авторизации, например).

Comment: скопировать в файл с расширением .py
заменить Hello world! на ваш HTML код
выполнить в командной строке

$ python you_file.py

открыть в браузере http://127.0.0.1:8000

Все. Вы наслаждаетесь сайтом на питоне.

Чтоб написать полноценное web-приложение вам еще понадобится парсинг GET/POST запросов, куки, сессии итд. 
Все это уже есть в фреймворках, которые вам тут предлагали.

Comment: Спасибо, может, еще литературу какую посоветуете, желательно на русском.

Comment: советую сначала изучить литературу по английскому языку, а потом литературу техническую читать на английском -- на русском не всегда можно найти актуальную информацию в полном объёме

Comment: Понял, вопросов нет, спасибо!

Answer (score 4):

Если очень хочется понять как всё это работает изнутри, советую этот мануал:
[`Python`: Веб-разработка без фреймворков](https://maluke.com/old/webdev)

Кроме того, можете почитать документацию по дефолтной библиотеке [`BaseHTTPServer`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html)

Answer (score 3):

Начните с Django или CherryPie, это достаточно простые для старта фреймворки для создания веб-приложений на питончике, как разберетесь с ними, то уже сами сможете решить, что интереснее, например, торнадо, твистед, гевент етс

UPD: в 3-ем питоне еще можно наследоваться от стандартного класса HttpServer, это удобно когда нужно написать простенький скрипт c возможностями веб-сервера без внешних зависимостей

Comment: Забыл написать, что хотелось бы обойтись без фреймворков (т.е. написать свой). Никакой информации в инете я не нашел.

Comment: urllib

но лучше почитайте про gevent

Comment: Во втором есть `BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler`

Answer (score 2):

Не понимаю, зачем вам писать свой фрэймворк с нуля и заниматься велосипедизмом, но данную информацию можно найти с помощью поисковиков: 
[Django своими руками часть 1: Собираем шаблоны для jinja2](http://habrahabr.ru/post/144717/)

Answer (score 0):

Если будете писать свой, то 90 процентов времени потратите на велосипед. Я бы предложил взять очень простой, можно сказать примитивный, но довольно продуманный и проверенный годами фреймворк. Например, Werkzeug.

С одной стороны он сэкономит кучу времени, выстроит мышление правильным образом.

С другой стороны все равно в силу простоты данного фреймворка подавляющую часть придется писать самому.